# Как настроить перенаправление почты корпоративного сайта на другой email?

Tags: email

Как настроить перенаправление (или копирование) почты корпоративного сайта webmail.site.xx на  другой email?

Comment: В панелях типа isp и т.п. есть управление почтой и можно поставить редиректы

Comment: Ответ на вопрос сильно зависит от того, как устроен почтовый сервер сайта. Это может быть панель яндекс:ПДД, гугл, панель типа ISP. В текущем виде вопрос слишком общий.